# Converting curses-based python script to MacOS App

Tags: python, exec, pyinstaller, curses, windowed

I am currently trying to convert a little program that has a **curses-based UI** to a macOS app using **Pyinstaller**.

I already successfully converted some programs to macOS applications, but none of them used curses, they all had a GUI.

I tried converting it using both the following command-line commands:

```
pyinstaller fileName.py --onedir --onefile -c
pyinstaller fileName.py --onedir --onefile -w
```

But every time I try to open the result of the conversion the terminal opens with the following command:

```
/Directory/of/the/exec; exit;
```

But **nothing else appears**.

How can I get a working macOS app?

Thank you very much for your precious help.